# no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError) Why is it happening?

Tags: ruby

I'm making a code that reads 3 integers, the first integer being the low interval and the second integer being the high interval, the third integer gives the amount of random numbers that will be displayed, I am getting the error

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Why? I thought it was its Consant type what was giving the problem but it changed it and it still said the same error :

```
Interval00, Interval01, Interval02 = gets.chomp.split(&:to_i)

puts "#{Interval00} #{Interval01} #{Interval02}"

array = (Interval00...Interval01).to_a.shuffle.take(Interval02)

array.each do |output| puts output end
```

Comment: What Ruby version are you using? Passing a block to `#split` present since Ruby 2.6.

Comment: `.shuffle.take(Interval02)` == `.sample(Interval02)`

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Ruby v2.6 `String#split` did not accept an optional block. That changed with v2.6. The last sentence of the v2.6 doc [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-split) states, "If a block is given, invoke the block with each split substring." The doc also shows that `str`, the receiver, is returned.

In the code below I have entered the string `"1 2 3"` in all cases. One might expect the presence of a block to mean that

```
gets.split { |s| s.to_i }
  #=> "1 2 3\n"
```

is the same as

```
gets.split.map { |s| s.to_i }
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

but clearly it is not, and the doc does not claim that it is. If a block is present, `split` *returns its receiver*, here `"1 2 3\n"` and the block merely performs calculations, much like `each`.

A simple example of how a block could be used is the following.

```
a = []
gets.split { |s| a << s.to_i }
  #=> "1 2 3\n" 
a #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your first line to this:

```
Interval00, Interval01, Interval02 = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
```

Also, you probably don't want to use an uppercase `I` in your variable name

The error is:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

This indicates you're trying to do something that expects an Integer, but you really have a String. If you inspect `Interval00` with a `puts`, after you chomp, you'll see it's a String, not an Integer.

When you try and `take` later, you're passing a String, not an Integer. You'll note:

```
[1, 2, 3].take("2")
```

Yields the same error. This is different than:

```
[1, 2, 3].take(2)
```

The line I suggested is what applies the `to_i` to your split data by using [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

Comment: Please explain why OP needs to change it to that. Also, variable case is subject to the coders own preference and has no bearing on this question or answer.

Comment: @CarlMarkham We're going to have to disagree on the variable case comment here but you're welcome to make an edit. A leading capital letter indicates it's a constant. If you're taking user input, it's not really a constant at that point.